# Running External Commands on an .exe from a Batch Code

Tags: batch-file, cmd, external, exe

I am trying to run an .exe program entirely from batch commands.  This program is in cmd prompt format (the .exe opens a command prompt and the user types in various commands to run).  After using this command:

```
START /b [path] [.exe file]
```

The desired program is running in the command window.  My problem arises next when the program prompts the user for commands (ex: "Enter Name - ").  To these prompts I wish to respond with commands that will be recognized by the program (ex: to the prompt "Enter Name - ", I wish to respond "NAME" and click enter/return to display the next prompt).

I have tried using the `echo` command but after successfully printing what I want into the command line, I need the program to hit enter/return to move on to the next prompt.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `START` command still admits stdin redirects. Therefore it should be possible for you to run,

```
START /b path\to\exe\file <path\to\canned\responses\file
```

For your specific case you could try,

```
@echo off
>tempinputfile echo reply foo
>>tempinputfile echo reply bar
start /b path\to\exe\file <tempinputfile
```